# @StateObject never gets destroyed

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am using @StateObject for creating a view model for my view. The problem is that the ViewModel is still in memory after closing the view and deinit is never called. If I open and close the view 10 times, the debug memory graph shows me 10 ViewModels. I created a very simple example to replicate the problem:

```
import SwiftUI

struct MySwiftUIView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentation
    @StateObject var viewModel = MyViewModel()

        var body: some View {
                Text("Hallo World.")
                    .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                    .navigationBarItems(leading: Button(
                        action: {
                            presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    },
                        label: { Text("back") }))
            }
    }

class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {
    init() {
        print(">> init")
    }

    deinit {
        print("[x] deinit")
    }
}
```

">> init" is printed every time when I am opening the view, but "[x] deinit" is never printed.

This is how I am opening the view:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                NavigationLink(destination: MySwiftUIView()){Text("NavigationLink")}
            }
        }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}
```

Does anybody have an idea why the ViewModel never gets destroyed?

I created a demo project in Xcode which can be found here: https://file.io/QQnHDvRNaGPP

Comment: I am using XCode 13 beta 5 and it works correctly for me. When the back button is pressed deinit prints correctly.

Comment: @runemonster: Which iOS version did you run it on? After I read your comment, I also tried it in XCode13 beta 5 and found out that it works fine on iOS15, but not iOS14.

Comment: @runemonster This question is not specific to iOS 15, so please test it on the current stable version of iOS. People are having problems now, even if it was fixed in iOS 15, they are looking for a solution for the current version, and when it'll be replaced by iOS 15, the fix will still be needed by many who support it.

Comment: So I tested and the reason the ViewModel is not calling deinit correctly is `navigationBarItems` does not correctly remove all references to the page when dismissing. What is your target version for your application? If it is 14 or above you could update to `ToolbarItem` which will make your deinit be called correctly.

Comment: @runemonster: My target version is iOS14. Thanks for your tipp, I will try it.

Comment: Also if you must use `navigationBarItems` for some reason. This Stack answer should help. I tried it and it worked. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61305155/6122879

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution which was suggested by runemonster in the comments worked. If I use Toolbar instead of navigationBarItems, the memory leak disappears:

```
struct MySwiftUIView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentation
    @StateObject var viewModel = MyViewModel()

        var body: some View {
                Text("Hallo World.")
                .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                            Button("Back") {
                                presentation.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
    }

class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {
    init() {
        print(">> init")
    }

    deinit {
        print("[x] deinit")
    }
}
```

Comment: Please file a radar on this and share it.